# Need to count unique but not count 43 and 43W as two different instances using Google Sheets Formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, count-unique

In the table below I am trying to get a COUNTUNIQUE formula working with INDIRECT("{RANGE}") that would show 3 unique numbers. Basically 43W and 43 need to reflect the same number.
I need to do this without using a staging sheet, so basically a one-liner would be great.

At the moment I have the following formula, but it just treats 43 and 43W as the same object:
`=COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT("RESPONSES!S3:X"))`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 20 |
| 2 | 19 | 43W |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any reason why you use INDIRECT?

Comment: @player0 I have a macro that I run that removes all the data in the sheet each night and it messes up the cell references if I don't use it. Even if I use $A$1 referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(i, COUNTUNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(i, "W", )))(INDIRECT("RESPONSES!S3:X")))
```

[image]

or just:

```
=INDEX(COUNTUNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("RESPONSES!S3:X"), "W", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, both of these work. I've gone with the second as it's easier to understand at a glance.